# Version control in Wolfram Cloud using git

Tags: wolfram-cloud, development

How do we integrate git or any other version control system with Wolfram Cloud?

I could run a shell command with [Run](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/Run.html) but in the Wolfram Cloud an error occurs saying

> Run::sandbox :  The operation  Run[date]  is not allowed while running
> in sandbox mode.

I guess this is done for security reasons, but the question remains. How do I version control a project? As the project grows, it is almost impossible to handle it without VCS.

Comment: Related: ["Integrating git with the Wolfram Language"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YStAQ23X0ug&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0po0k_FiuFqDuVotoZhX7_&index=14) Presentation on the Wolfram YouTube channel.

Comment: It is not currently integrated into Wolfram. Do you know of some workarounds?